# Having SQL Syntax error in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am new to MySQL stored procedure. No clue why am I getting the following Error. Please help debug this.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO this_user_id, this_user_fullname FROM user_master WHERE user_username = @th' at line 3

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE loginUser(IN this_user_name VARCHAR(100), IN this_user_password VARCHAR(100), OUT this_user_id BIGINT(11), OUT this_user_fullname VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id, user_full_name INTO this_user_id, this_user_fullname FROM user_master WHERE user_username = this_user_name AND user_password = this_user_password) THEN
    SET this_user_id = NULL;
    SET this_user_fullname = NULL;
  END IF;
END$$
```

#### My table structure is

Table Name: user_master

user_id bigint(11)  No
user_full_name  varchar(100)    Yes     NULL
user_username   varchar(60) Yes     NULL
user_password   varchar(45) Yes     NULL
user_security_question  varchar(225)    Yes     NULL
user_security_answer    varchar(255)    Yes     NULL
user_salt   varchar(30) Yes     NULL
user_status enum('ACTIVE', 'SUSPENDED', 'PENDING')  Yes     NULL
user_last_login_time    timestamp   Yes     NULL
user_last_logout_time   timestamp   Yes     NULL

IndexesDocumentation

PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  user_id 4   A   No
user_username_UNIQUE    BTREE   Yes No  user_username   4   A   Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just doing this?

```
BEGIN
    -- Initialize the variables
    SET this_user_id = NULL;
    SET this_user_fullname = NULL;

    -- Set them
    SELECT user_id, user_full_name
    INTO this_user_id, this_user_fullname
    FROM user_master
    WHERE user_username = this_user_name AND user_password = this_user_password;

   . . .
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not a bad idea, but I still want to know where I made the mistake.